# reading stdin containing newlines in matlab

Tags: matlab

`stdin` can be read in Matlab using the `input` function as demonstrated in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23876233/873757). For instance:

```
printf "1\t2\n" | matlab -nojvm -nodesktop -nosplash -r "str=input('','s')"
```

Trying to read data with multiple newline characters fails because the first one signals the end of the `input` command:

```
printf "1\t2\n3\t4\n" | matlab -nojvm -nodesktop -nosplash -r "str=input('','s')"
  str =  1    2
  >>     3    4
         |
  Error: Unexpected MATLAB expression.
```

I have tried other possibilities including `fscanf(0,...)`,  `fscanf('',...)`, `fopen(0,'r')`, and `fopen('','r')`, to no avail. I wish to read lines of tab-separated data piped from another process, ideally directly into a cell array, or into a string which I can then parse myself. I could of course loop over `input` until the end of the stream, but I am wondering whether there is not some way to gather all the input at once.