# run Matlab script with system argument in ubuntu terminal or bash script

Tags: bash, matlab, terminal, arguments

I want to run matlab script on ubuntu terminal or bash scripts with system argument.

for example, in python,

```
sample.py


variable_name=sys.argv[1]

print(variable_name)
```

and, run like this.

```
$ python sample.py arguments
```

How can I run matlab code like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But, what do you want to do? Matlab have a `system` function
[system](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html)

If you want request user input and save it, [input](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/input.html)

Comment: okay I'll try it!

Comment: I'll look that document! I'm trying to do run same matlab file multiple times with different input variables automatically..

Comment: Something like this? [How to read from stdin in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23875734/how-to-read-from-stdin-in-matlab)